# How to track Java parent thread id using aspectj?

Tags: java, multithreading, aspectj, aop

I am trying to track to obtain the parent thread id of each new thread created in a program using AspectJ. Since a new thread starts execution using the start() method, I thought the following technique should work:

```
aspect getParentThread {
    pointcut threadStarting(): call(public void start());
    Object around(): threadStarting() {
         long parentThread = Thread.currentThread().getId();
         Object ret = proceed();
         long newThread = Thread.currentThread().getId();
         if (parentThread != newThread) {
              /*Store parentThread id in data structure */
         }
         return ret;
     }
}
```

But this simply does not work. Although the advice executes, even after proceed() completes there is just a single thread id. So what am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that all of your code executes in the parent thread, including the code after the child thread starts, because the `start()` method is called from and executes in the parent thread.

You could try getting the ID of the new thread from the `Thread` object on which the `start()` method is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right -- it is easily possible to get it from the Thread object (instead of using current thread).

Answer (score 2):

*Warren Dew* is right, but I want to add some sample code in order to show how you can easily do it with AspectJ. You do not even need an `around()` advice, a simple `before()` is enough.

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {}
            },
            "first thread"
        ).start();
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {}
            },
            "second thread"
        ).start();
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect ThreadStartInterceptor {
    before(Thread childThread) :
        call(public void Thread+.start()) &&
        target(childThread)
    {
        System.out.printf(
            "%s%n  Parent thread: %3d -> %s%n  Child thread:  %3d -> %s%n",
            thisJoinPoint,
            Thread.currentThread().getId(),
            Thread.currentThread().getName(),
            childThread.getId(),
            childThread.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

- As you can see, I am limiting method interception to `Thread+`, i.e. to `Thread` and subclass instances. I am doing this explicitly even though it is not strictly necessary because the next point already does it implicitly:
- I am also binding the child thread to a variable which can be used neatly from within the aspect.

**Console log:**

```
call(void java.lang.Thread.start())
  Parent thread:   1 -> main
  Child thread:   11 -> first thread
call(void java.lang.Thread.start())
  Parent thread:   1 -> main
  Child thread:   12 -> second thread
```